# XSD schema, SOAP, REST and a MESS!

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, schema

I think this person hit on my problem [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506140/how-do-i-send-this-soap-xml-in-perl/1510730#1510730)

I have a schema and a pdf that has something like the below

I have NO WSDL file. Absolutely none, i do have a large schema (apiName.xsd). It seems like i need to do something with it but i have no clue what.

```
<xs:element name="CheckDomain"> 
<xs:complexType> 
<xs:sequence> 
<xs:element name="domain" type="domainRef"/> 
<xs:element name="suggestions" type="xs:boolean" default="false" minOccurs="0"/> 
</xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Duplicate. Not a question. Makes no sense.

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times, with different wording, expecting a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what are you *trying* to do with it? :)

Many platforms have 1)a tool that takes XSD schema convert it into classes, and 2)a way to convert instances of these classes into XML.

E.g. if you're using .NET:

- Use xsd.exe tool to convert your XSD file into classes
- Use the classes as usual, e.g. CheckDomain c = new CheckDomain(); c.suggestions=true;
- Use the XmlSerializer class to convert this to XML

I assume you want to send the XML to some server somewhere afterwards, but you didn't give enough info to be able to tell how to do this.

Comment: I barely know the details myself. I have a schema and a link to the remote url (which ends with .exe). I am using perl.

Comment: Chances are it's not really SOAP then. Just construct a chunk of XML according to the schema, and do an HTTP POST to that URL with that chunk of XML as the message body. Try setting Content-Type header to "application/xml" or "text/xml" as well, some servers are picky about this.